# Scala ListBuffer add-all behavior is not consistent, some elements are lost

Tags: scala

I came across a Scala collection behavior that somewhat dubious. Is this an expected behavior?

Following is a simplified code to reproduce the issue.

```
import scala.collection.mutable.{ Map => MutableMap }
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

  val relationCache = MutableMap.empty[String, String]
  val relationsToFlush = new ListBuffer[String]()

  def addRelation(relation: String) = relationCache(relation) = relation

  Range(0,170).map("string-#" + _).foreach(addRelation(_))
  val relations = relationCache.values.toSeq /* Bad */
  // val relations = relationCache.map(_._2).toSeq  /* Good */
  relationCache.clear
  relationsToFlush ++= relations
  relationsToFlush.size
```

Has two collections, mutable map (relationCache) and mutable list (relationsToFlush). relationCache takes elements and at later point it should be transferred to relationsToFlush and the cache should be cleared up.

However, not all elements transferred to relationsToFlush, output as below:

```
scala>   relationsToFlush ++= relCache
res14: relationsToFlush.type = ListBuffer(string-#80, string-#27)

scala>   relationsToFlush.size
res15: Int = 2
```

Where else if the code changed to

```
    val relations = relationCache.map(_._2).toSeq  /* Good */
```

Then we get the expected result (170 elements)

My guess is 'good' code creates new mutable list with those element while the other returns directly from map, hence its lost when clear is called on map. However, shouldn't the reference count gets bumped up when it returns to `relations` variable?

Scala Version: 2.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've stumbled across one of the vagaries of the `Seq` trait.

Since `Seq` is a trait, and not a `class`, it's not really a collection type distinct from the others, leading some to refer to it as a failed abstraction.

Consider the following REPL session. (Scala 2.12.7)

```
scala> List(1,2,3).toSeq
res4: scala.collection.immutable.Seq[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> Stream(1,2,3).toSeq
res5: scala.collection.immutable.Seq[Int] = Stream(1, ?)

scala> Vector(1,2,3).toSeq
res6: scala.collection.immutable.Seq[Int] = Vector(1, 2, 3)
```

Notice how the underlying collection type is retained. In particular the lazy `Stream` has not realized all its elements. That's what's happening here:

```
relationCache.values.toSeq
```

The `toSeq` transformation returns a `Stream` and nothing thereafter is forcing the realization of the rest of the elements.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is combining lazy evaluation with mutable data structures.

The value of `relations` is lazy and is not computed until it is used. Since it is based on a `mutable.Map` collection, the results will be based on whatever that `mutable.Map` has **at the time `relations` is first used**.
To complicate things, `relations` is actually a `Stream` which means that those values are locked the first time they are read, meaning the subsequent changes to the `mutable.Map` will not affect that value of `relations`.

The simple fix is to use `toList` rather than `toSeq`, because `List` is not a lazy collection and will be evaluated immediately.